# How to generate an intermediate table in code first using Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Right now I have the following three classes:

```
public class Customer{
public int Id {get;set;}
public ICollection<State> StatesLivedIn {get;set;}
}

public class Business{
public int Id {get;set;}
public ICollection<State> StatesLocatedIn {get;set;}
}

public class State{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like for code first to generate the following two tables:

```
CustomerStates(Customer Id, State Id) 
BusinessStates(Business Id, State Id)
```

Is there a way to generate this with fluent api?

Comment: do you want to create model also or just tables?

Answer (score 0):

With Code first EF decide wich tables to create.
In your case a better model could be this

```
public class State
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Business> BusinessesLocatedIn {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> CustomerLivesIn {get;set;}    
}
```

where you specify that a state can have several Customers who lives in it and several Business located in it

This should be enough for EF otherwise you can use HasMany/WithMany fluent methods (i.e. `HasMany(t => t.CustomersLivesIn).WithMany(t => t.StatesLivesIn);`

PS: remember virtual if you need lazy load